# Printing formatted outputs in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to print code that is formatted in the following way:

```
Iteration 1:
# A matrix goes here
Iteration 2:
# Another matrix goes here
Iteration 3:
# Another...
Iteration 4:
# Last matrix


# Final matrix is printed again
```

My function is supposed to print in such a way if my variable verbose is true. All the matrices are stored in a list. Here's my code:

```
converge <- function(A, eps = 1e-6, itmax = 100, verbose = TRUE) {
  counter <- 1
  iterations <- list()
  B0 <- compute.B(A, 1)
  iterations[[1]] <- B0

  if (itmax == 1) {
    return(B0)
  }

  for (i in 2:itmax) {

    B1 <- compute.B(A, i)

    if (sqrt(sum((B1 - B0)^2)) < eps) {
      break()
    }

    B0 <- B1
    iterations[[i]] <- B1
    counter <- counter + 1
  }

  # Shows last four iterations
  if (verbose && counter >= 4) {
    for (i in (counter - 3):counter) {
      print(iterations[[i]])
    }
  }

  return(B1)
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: I just want to format the output similar what I typed above. Right now, it just prints the results without the "Iteration" number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `paste` to format your output. For example you can do this:

```
cat(paste(paste("Iteration", i,":"),   ## Iteration i:
            round(iterations[[i]],2),             ## the matrix i    
            sep='\n')                    ## in a new line
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get really weird output:

`[1] "Iteration 1 :\n0.35347146208363"    "Iteration 1 :\n-0.0820577636426526"
[3] "Iteration 1 :\n-0.0201823231716632" "Iteration 1 :\n-0.0820577636426526"
[5] "Iteration 1 :\n0.255282867771685"   "Iteration 1 :\n-0.0355935599686512"
[7] "Iteration 1 :\n-0.0201823231716632" "Iteration 1 :\n-0.0355935599686512"
[9] "Iteration 1 :\n0.391245670144684"`